# Cannot run Xamarin.iOS apps on macbook from Windows Parallels (cannot install Broker)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, parallels

I am trying to build a Xamarin iOS app and debug it in my mac simulator from Windows. I haven't been able to get this working all day and it is pretty time sensitive at this point.

I have updated and ensured both VS mac and windows are on the same update channels, have the same versions of Xamarin installed, cleared the cache on both mac and windows, made sure I can SSH into my machine, I can actually run the mac agent on a remote machine over VPN, but the connection is EXTREMELY slow and it is causing all sorts of different issues so debugging with it isn't an option.

The only thing I've noticed is that everyone else who seems to have this issue and shares info from their Xamarin diagnostic output shows that they're installing from Broker 4.6.* while mine seems to be trying to install Broker 1.1.6.*. This seems pretty odd, but I don't really know anything about this as I have nearly zero background in Xamarin and have just picked up this project as my company's Xamarin dev left last summer and I am developing a NativeScript app for us... someone thought they were kind of similar I guess?

Anyway, here is my output from when I attempt to connect... lastly, I used my mac's IP because the windows parallels install couldn't resolve the machine name and pointing localhost or 127.0.0.1 doesn't seem to work either although I'm not entirely sure why.

```
Checking host configuration for connecting to '192.168.86.29'...
Checking SSH configuration...
Checking available disk space...
Checking Mono installation...
The required Mono version to install on the Mac couldn't be determined, so the Mono validation will not continue.
Checking Xamarin iOS installation...
The required Xamarin.iOS version to install on the Mac couldn't be determined, so the Xamarin.iOS validation will not continue.
Checking host configuration for connecting to '192.168.86.29'...
Host '192.168.86.29' is configured correctly
Starting connection to '192.168.86.29'...
Installing Broker 1.1.6.181...
Unable to install the Broker
Starting connection to '192.168.86.29'...
Starting disconnection from 192.168.86.29...
Starting disconnection from 192.168.86.29...
The connection to '192.168.86.29' has been finished
An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
```

Comment: It is necessary to clean some folders both on Mac and Windows

On Mac
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Clearing_the_Broker_IDB_Build_and_Designer_Agents_on_the_Mac

And on Windows 
/Users/YourAccountName/AppData/Xamarin/MonoTouch

Comment: Also look over this troubleshooting guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac  and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#errors-due-to-existing-build-host-processes-on-the-mac

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually went through and tried deleting all of the cache folders I found in that first link and have gone through all of the troubleshooting guide. The only thing that I haven't done that one user suggested was to reinstall macOS.... which I will not consider an option at this point........